# get String from Java Graphics instance

Tags: java, java-2d

I have some code snippet that goes like below

```
:

Graphics g;      // Java Graphics class

g.drawString("text", x, y);   // x, y for coordinate info, "text" is now an image object

:
```

Can I get "text" back into a String from the Graphics instance?

Since I want to use the String data as a key for getting some data from a table.

Comment: I don't think so. Why do you need this?

Comment: Oh, the context is that if I click on a node on the presentation layer, some additional information of the node should be presented to the user.

Answer (score 1):

The best approach is probably to store the text in a `String` variable, and get it from there instead.

Comment: Then, when a click event occurrs on a node graphics, there is no way for system to know the what the text on the node graphic represents?

Comment: @CaliaKim: Not easily, no. By that time the text is just a bunch of pixels.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will have to find other means.

Answer (score 0):

No, the `Graphics` instance just draws the text on the screen or an image as pixels. It does not remember what the text is that you drew, so it can't tell you.

You'll have to store the text some other way in your program, so that you can get it back later for whatever purpose you need it for (such as getting data from a table).

Comment: It does seem so. I already store the node object represented by the graphical node into a hashmap. But when I click on the graphical node, there is no way of telling JVM what node to get just by clicking on the graphic node that represents the real node object. Is there a better way to represent the graph data structure other than using Java Graphics on the presentation layer to represents the set of nodes? Should I use Button object?

Comment: You most likely already have a data structure that represents the graph you're drawing. Store the relevant data in there, instead of trying to get the data back from the image.

Comment: Then my presentation layer gets useless?

Comment: You shouldn't store the data (the model) in the presentation layer.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I understand what you mean. I don't store model at presentation layer. The presentation layers only represents the model, and when I click on a node of the screen, a contexual menu pops up and gives the menu item for deleting or modifying a data object represented by the graphical node. And I found the graphic does not contains any String data in it. I should find some other way. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by adding two tables that each memorize the X and Y coordinate for the node instance being generated at the presentation layer and at model layer.

At runtime, node images continue to change its position and these events are all updated.

When I click on a node image on Panel instance, it gives the id of the node instance.

The reason why two tables are required is that only when the id returned by calling the X, Y position of the node image refers to the same node object is the evidence that the event is for the node object represented by the clicked node image. Now I realize I could have used multi-key table.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

// * Represents node at presentation layer and its model

public class NodeObject 
{
// * node id
private int id;

// * coordinate on Panel
public double x;
public double y;

// * coordinate change
private  double dx;
private  double dy;

// * isFixed
public  boolean fixed;

// * node name
public String nodeName;

// * connected node object id list ( redundant when edge is used )
public List<Integer> connectedNodeIdList;

// * connected edge object id list
private List<Integer> connectedEdgeIdList;

// * constructor
public NodeObject()
{}

// * constructor
public NodeObject( int _id )
{
    // * initialization
    this.id = _id;

    // * default
    this.nodeName = "default";

    // * connected node id list
    this.connectedNodeIdList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
}

// * Constructor ( when node name is given )
public NodeObject( int _id, String _nodeName )
{
    // * node id
    this.id = _id;

    // * node name
    this.nodeName = _nodeName;

    // * connected node id list
    this.connectedNodeIdList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    // * connected edge id list 
    this.connectedEdgeIdList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
}

// * set node name
public void setNodeName( String nName )
{
     this.nodeName = nName;
}

// * get node id
public int getNodeId()
{
    return this.id;
}

// * get node name
public String getNodeName()
{
    return this.nodeName;
}

// * get node name and id in String
public String getNodeNameWithID()
{
      String id = Integer.toString( this.getNodeId() );

      return ( this.nodeName + "-" +id );
}

// * store connected node
public boolean addSingleNode( int nid )
{
    if ( this.connectedNodeIdList.contains( nid ) == true )
    {
        return true;   // this node is already connected
    }
    else
    {
        // * register
        this.connectedNodeIdList.add( nid );

        // * this is the first time this node is connected
        return false;
    }
}

// * unregister a node
public boolean removeConnectedSingleNode( int nid )
{
      // * it was registered before
      if ( this.connectedNodeIdList.contains( nid ) == true )
      {
           this.connectedNodeIdList.remove( nid );

           return true; //  it had been registered and now unregistered ( only at model layer )
      }
      else
      {
           return false;   // it has not been registered before.
      }
}

// * add edge id
public boolean addSingleEdge( int eid )
{
    if ( this.connectedEdgeIdList.contains( eid ) == true )
    {
        return true;   // already registered edge
    }
    else
    {
        // * registered
        this.connectedEdgeIdList.add( eid );

        // * this is the first time this edge was connected
        return false;
    }
}

// * remove edge
public boolean removeConnectedSingleEdge( int eid )
{
      // * registered before
      if ( this.connectedEdgeIdList.contains( eid ) == true )
      {
           this.connectedEdgeIdList.remove( eid );

           return true; // now removed ( model level )
      }
      else
      {
           return false;   // it has not been registered before
      }
}

// * return edge id list
public List<Integer> getEdgeIdList()
{
    return this.connectedEdgeIdList;
}

//////// for visualization on Panel instance ///////

// * X coordinate setting
public void setNodePositionX( Double xPos )
{
     this.x = xPos;
}

// * Y coordinate setting
public void setNodePositionY( Double yPos )
{
     this.y = yPos;
}

// * change of node position
public void changeNodePosition( Double changeX, Double changeY )
{
     this.x = this.x + changeX;
     this.y = this.y + changeY;
}

// * position difference
public void changeNodePositionDifference( Double changeDX, Double changeDY )
{
     this.dx = this.dx + changeDX;
     this.dy = this.dy + changeDY;
}

// * update node position difference
public void updateNodePositionDifference( Double changeDX, Double changeDY )
{
     this.dx = changeDX;
     this.dy = changeDY;
}

// * get X pos
public double getNodePositionX()
{
     return this.x;
}

// * get Y pos
public double getNodePositionY()
{
     return this.y;
}

// * get dx
public double getNodePositionDX()
{
     return this.dx;
}

// * get dy
public double getNodePositionDY()
{
     return this.dy;
}
}
```

And the Graph class goes like below

```
public class Graph extends Panel implements Runnable, MouseListener, MouseMotionListener, ItemListener
{   

// * number of nodes
public int nnodes;

// * node generator
public NodeGenerator ndGenerator;

// * memorize the node coordinate
public Map<Integer, Integer> xCoordinateTbl;   // key : coordinate / value : node id
public Map<Integer, Integer> yCoordinateTbl;

// * node tbl
public Map<Integer, NodeObject> nodeTbl;
```

Once mouse click event occurs, it is handled like below

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) 
{
    // * get node id of the node object being referred to at the presentation layer
    Integer nid = getNodeId( e.getPoint().x, e.getPoint().y );

    // * remove node on the presentation layer and of the model at the same time
     removeSingleNode( nid );  
}
```